# Adding Constraint using VFL - iOS Swift

Tags: swift, autolayout

I am getting myself introduced to VFL and I am trying out something which I need some help.

I have the image view aligned like in below image in portrait mode.
[image]

In landscape the view looks as below

[image]

In landscape I want the image to be centered along Y-Axis i.e and little bit up than shown in the image.

I have the below VFL code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    googleSignButton = UIImageView()
    googleSignButton!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    googleSignButton!.image = UIImage(named: "google.png")
    self.view!.addSubview(googleSignButton!)

    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 50
    let views:[String:UIImageView] = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("google",googleSignButton!))
    let metrics = ["dim" : buttonWidth,
                       "horizontalPadding" : (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - (3 * buttonWidth)) / 3,
            "verticalPadding" : (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.5) - (buttonWidth * 0.5)]

        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-horizontalPadding-[google(dim)]", options:[] , metrics: metrics, views: views)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-verticalPadding-[google(dim)]", options:[] , metrics: metrics, views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraint)
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraint)
}
```

How can I achieve that. Potrait mode looks fine and in landscape, the image has to be centered vertically.

Thank you.

Edit

Updated Code:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

        coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in



            }) { (UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void in

                self.calculateConstraints()

        }
    }

    func calculateConstraints() {

        let buttonWidth:CGFloat = Common.sharedCommon.calculateDimensionForDevice(50)

        let views:[String:UIImageView] = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("google",googleSignButton!))
        let metrics = ["dim" : 50.0,
            "horizontalPadding" : (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - (3 * buttonWidth)) / 3,
            "verticalPadding" : (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.5) - (buttonWidth * 0.5)]


        if let horizontal = horizontalConstraint, let vertical = verticalConstraint {

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([horizontal])
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints([vertical])
        }

        horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-horizontalPadding-[google(dim)]", options:[] , metrics: metrics, views: views)[0]
        verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-verticalPadding-[google(dim)]", options:[] , metrics: metrics, views: views)[0]

        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([horizontalConstraint!,verticalConstraint!])

}
```

Images:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Where are you calling this code?

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that the constraints don't get updated on rotation, so it is using the same vertical constraint for landscape.

First, you'll actually want to save your constraints in properties for deactivation purposes. In your view controller:

```
var verticalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]?
var horizontalConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint]?
```

Then, wrap your constraint code in a function (note I modified it slightly):

```
function calculateButtonConstraints() {
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 50
    let views:[String:UIImageView] = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("google",googleSignButton!))
    let metrics = ["dim" : buttonWidth,
                   "horizontalPadding" : (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width - (3 * buttonWidth)) / 3,
        "verticalPadding" : (UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height * 0.5) - (buttonWidth * 0.5)]

    if let horizontal = horizontalConstraints, let vertical = verticalConstraints {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(horizontal)
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivateConstraints(vertical)
    }

    horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-horizontalPadding-[google(dim)]", options:[] , metrics: metrics, views: views)
    verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-verticalPadding-[google(dim)]", options:[] , metrics: metrics, views: views)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(horizontalConstraints!)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(verticalConstraints!)
}
```

Note that I used `NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints:` instead, as that is the preferred way. Also, that is in part with `deactivateConstraints:`.

Then, instead of that code in `viewDidLoad:`, put this:

```
calculateButtonConstraints()
```

Next, add this to your view controller:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

    coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition(nil, completion: { [unowned self]
        self.calculateButtonConstraints()
    })

    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)

}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (corrected some syntax errors) Looks like it's working but the image view looks far bigger than the size defined in the code.

Comment: @slysid That's odd. Can you link an image of the new, bigger size?

Comment: @slysid I edited my post (fixed the syntax), don't know if that changes anything.

Comment: I have updated my code and image i am getting in the description.

Comment: Okay, check my post with the updated code. I made some vital changes.

Comment: I think it's better to do this with one set of constraints that are applied differently based on size class or priority. That way you don't have to handle the orientation change yourself, which can get messy. Also remember that other events besides rotation can change your available screen space.

Comment: @AaronBrager `viewWillTransitionToSize:` doesn't actually get called ONLY on rotation. It gets called every time the size of the view changes. Also, I don't know what @slysid wants in the many other cases (screen size, orientation, iOS 9 multitasking, etc.).